# Intuition of the expectation.

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. What is the intuition behind the definition $$\mathbb E[X]=\int_\Omega X(\omega) \, \mathrm d \mathbb P(\omega )\text{ ?}$$

I don't see in what for example $$\int_X f \, \mathrm d \mu$$
would be the average of $f$ on the measurable space $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, for $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ a measure space, if $\mu(X)<\infty $, a reasonable definition for the average of $f$ would be $$\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_X f \, \mathrm d \mu.$$
Since $\mathbb P(\Omega)=1$, you get

$$\mathbb E[X]=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(\Omega)}\int_\Omega X \, \mathrm d \mathbb P = \int_\Omega X \, \mathrm d \mathbb P,$$
what make sense.

Answer (score 0):

A convex combination of numbers is a weighted average. Integration against a probability measure is a generalization of convex combination and it, too, represents a weighted average.